# Есть ли разница в работе кода?

Tags: java, многопоточность

```
public class Solution {
    static int count = 15;
    static volatile int createdThreadCount;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new GenerateThread());
    }

    public static class GenerateThread extends Thread {
        public String toString() {
            return this.getName() + " created";
        }

        public GenerateThread() {
            super(String.valueOf(++createdThreadCount));
            start();
        }

        public void run() {
            if (createdThreadCount < count) {
                System.out.println(new GenerateThread().toString());
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Или Run через While

```
public class Solution {
    static int count = 15;
    static volatile int createdThreadCount;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new GenerateThread());
    }

    public static class GenerateThread extends Thread {
        public String toString() {
            return this.getName() + " created";
        }

        public GenerateThread() {
            super(String.valueOf(++createdThreadCount));
            start();
        }

        public void run() {
            while (createdThreadCount < count) {
                System.out.println(new GenerateThread().toString());
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: как запутано. А вы пробовали запустить эти куски кода и посмотреть, есть ли разница?

Comment: В целом я уже понял)) Оба кода в принципе дают схожий результат, но один последовательно создает нити, в другом несколько нитей одновременно создают нити) По выводу данных можно только увидеть разницу, что номера вылетают не по порядку при использовании while

Comment: Первый правильнее. У вас поток по окончанию себя создаёт новый экземпляр. Второй вариант плодит потоки не завершаясь. Причём эти потоки также ветвятся. Нарушится логика контроля и будет неуправляемый процесс из множества незакрытых потоков.

Comment: Я думаю тут оба варианта не правильные. Тут проверка createdThreadCount < count и создание потока (инкремент счетчика) должны быть атомарными (в критической секции), а то получается, что множество потоков могут убедиться что 14 < 15 одновременно и каждый создаст еще по крайне мере по одному потоку. Т.е. счетчик у тебя будет createdThreadCount больше 15.